# Are MySQL databases always stored in /var on CentOS? 

Tags: mysql, centos, dedicated-server, centos5, var

Are MySQL databases always stored in `/var` on CentOS?

Specifically - If a new CentOS/cPanel server that needs to support MySQL, doesn't have that partition, but only has these, does that mean MySQL data is somehow being stored in a temporary dump somewhere?

```
/dev/sda3              /
tmpfs                  /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              /boot
/usr/tmpDSK            /tmp
```

Comment: The data directory can be relocated if you really want/need to do that.  So it may not be __always__ stored under /var, but that is the standard location.

Comment: Are there advantages to storing MySQL on /var ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case `/var` is stored on `/dev/sda3` as a subdirectory of `/`.

The default `datadir` for MySQL is `/var/lib/mysql` and as long as you do not change the configuration, the database files are stored in this directory.

Answer (score 4):

In *nix, if a directory is not a separate mount then it is part of its parent mount. In this case, `/var` is considered part of `/`.